# how to escape html entities in grid?

Tags: extjs

I have grid column:

```
{
    header: "",
    sortable: false,
    id: 'value',
    dataIndex: 'value',
    hidden: false,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        allowBlank: false
    }
}
```

How to escape html entities  only in renderer function for this column ?

Answer (score 12):

The **renderer** property of a column definition can take either a function or the string name of one of Ext.util.Format's methods. In this case you can use the **htmlEncode** method by declaring the column as:

```
{
    header: "",
    sortable: false,
    id: 'value',
    dataIndex: 'value',
    hidden: false,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        allowBlank: false
    },
    renderer: 'htmlEncode'
}
```

Comment: I had to use `renderer: Ext.util.Format.htmlFormat` (rather than a string; in Ext3).

Comment: Couldn't find any such named property. Can you please help to identify where should I apply this `htmlEncode`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a autoEncode property on the EditorGridPanel.

"True to automatically HTML encode and decode values pre and post edit (defaults to false)."

Just set it to true.

```
autoEncode: true
```

Answer (score 1):

hi write this code in app.js file
//code for grid xss

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.column.Column, {
defaultRenderer: Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode
});
```